# When does this sequence of functions converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For any given function $g_0(x)$ let $$g_1(x)=\frac{g_0(x)}{g_0'(x)}$$ $$g_2(x)=\frac{g_1(x)}{g_1'(x)}$$ $$\vdots$$ $$g_{n+1}(x)=\frac{g_n(x)}{g_n'(x)}$$ Does $g(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}g_n(x)$ exist?

I don't have any clue how to tackle this. For example if $g_0(x)=x^n$ then $g_2(x)=x$, which reamins the same but functions like $e^x$ end up in something like $\frac{1}{0}$ or even something like $x^2-1$ gets crazy

This does not solve the problem but manipulation gives $$g_n(x)=g_0(x)\cdot\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{g_{n-i}'(x)}$$

I have also found that even number terms of the sequence are somehow "wavy" for a lot of starting functions (making the odd terms similar to the tangent function)